# How to write SQL query to get following results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL query to get the result from table.

Here is the practical problem: in my database there is table named `Contact`.
In that table there are two columns `Calling_Person` and `Called_Person`.

Assume that this table contains following data:

Table: `Contact`

```
Calling_Person      Called_Person
--------------------------------------
AB                CD
CD                AB
AB                EF
EF                AB
AB                PQ
PQ                XY
XY                UV
XY                ZW
UV                XY
```

From the above table, we want only the person who called to each other.

Expected output:

```
Calling_Person      Called_Person
--------------------------------------
AB                 CD
AB                 EF
XY                 UV
```

In above table,

- AB and CD called to each other
- AB and EF called to each other
- XY and UV called to each other

I have written following query but it gives the result as:

```
select * 
from test
where id2 in (select id1 from test as t
              where id2 in (select id1 from test where id1 = t.id2)
             )
```

Result:

```
Calling_Person      Called_Person
--------------------------------------
AB          CD
CD          AB
AB          EF
EF          AB
XY          UV
UV          XY
```

Comment: Isn't this just `WHERE ID1 = 'AB'`? What is the actual problem you have here?

Comment: No. It is the dynamic value.

Comment: What "Dynamic Value"? Do you mean a variable/parameter? I.e. `WHERE ID1 = @YourParameter`?

Comment: The value of the column is not know. It should be filtered automatically at run time.  I have created this source data on assumption.

Comment: *"The value of the column is not know."* so how should we know it, if *you* don't...? To repeat myself *"What is the **actual problem** you have here?"* If you don't explain the real problem, we can't help you.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you're trying to group identical pairs (e.g. `(a,b)` and `(b,a)`) together. You need to mark one of the rows as the "main" row using the condition `id1 < id2` and check if a match exists:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t AS t1
WHERE id1 < id2 AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM t AS t2
    WHERE t2.id1 = t1.id2 AND t2.id2 = t1.id1
)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to get the expected results. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all pairs, then it is sufficient to use:

```
select t.*
from t 
where id1 < id2;
```

If you have some pairs, then:

```
select t.*
from t 
where id1 < id2 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id1 = t.id2 and t2.id2 = t.id1
                 );
```

If you actually have duplicates, use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct id1, id2
from t 
where id1 < id2 or
      not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.id1 = t.id2 and t2.id2 = t.id1
                 );
```